# node.js + oracledb - Interrupt ongoing query

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

I'm, currently developing a web interface in node.js for directly executing SELECT queries from a log table in an Oracle Database. For that purpose I'm using [oracledb](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb).

Since our log table is quite big, the SELECT query might take a long time, even if the result set is just a few rows (< 10).

I want to allow users to interrupt the operation if it is taking too long. Using cursors or limiting the number of rows does not help since the query itself takes a long time to complete.

The only way it seems possible to interrupt a query previously started [using this method](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#execute) is by closing the connection to the database [using this method](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#connectionclose). Is there any other way to interrupt an ongoing query using `oracledb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution. In order to stop an ongoing operation, one must call the `break` method on the connection, as described [here](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#break).